# Export quote character to variable

Tags: unix

I want to export a double quote character ( " ) to a variable which I can use further in the script.
Something like QUOTE_CHARACTER=$(printf "\1")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's simple enough, just enclose it in single quotes:

```
$ v='"'
$ echo $v
"
```

Or escape it:

```
$ v=\"
$ echo $v
"
```

Or, but there's no reason to complicate things this much, use

```
$ v=$'"'
$ echo $v
"
```